# Timer loop or an alternative?

Tags: java, android, timer

I can't reveal much code but i'l be writing rough pseudocode that i want to achieve:

```
if(state){
timer loop starts:
      [//block
        logic runs
        view.postInvalidate calls
      ]
}

if(!state){
timer loop stops
}
```

and i want timer to execute above block(i have commented in intervals) i.e i want that block to be executed every 1 sec(1000ms).

can you please guide me to achieve. I have used this link http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html to achieve that but i can't make my block code to run in every 1000ms intervals.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you make your code run every one second? Please describe the exact problem.

Comment: cuz i want some delay. There are two bitmap that i want to draw consecutively. But i want some delay in between each drawing of two bitmaps on my view canvas
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your main loop can be accomplished by using Thread.sleep(n) where n is the number of milliseconds to sleep.

So you do

```
while(true){
    doSomething();
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: You need to record the amount of time taken by the doSomething() method and, from that result, calculate the amount of time uyour thread should sleep. Otherwise you are going to slip from your execution rate.

Comment: private Thread animationThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    
      @Override
      public void run() {
    
       //logic code runs
       
       try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       }
      }
         
        });

Above is my requirement.
so i want something like if state is on my thread starts and runs login in 500ms interval but its not happening.

Thanks

Comment: Examine the LunarLander example (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html). There you have a ready made animation loop and app state handling code.